# ark - What happens with base on dino when it dies

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I can't seem to find an answer to this (probably because words base, dino and die are too common).

So... let's say you get a bronto, or a quetz, or a pleis, or a para, etc. You build platform, and on that platform you build a base. Let's say metal. And a vault inside for the fun of it. What happens if the bronto/quetz/para/whatever dies? Since the base is on bronto/(list of creatures here) saddle... it just vanishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the dinosaur is killed then the platform on the dinosaur and anything on it is also destroyed. The platformsaddle can be recollected from the corpse.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a correct answer. Ok, except, you can recollect the platform-saddle. But everything else is destroyed, even a vault did not survive the fall from that hight for me.